# Is it possible to have an aws EKS infrastructure as code?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-eks, infrastructure-as-code

Is it possible to declare "a complete production level EKS with other aws services" using terraform? I know that terraform has [an eks module](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/eks/aws/latest) and [an aws provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs). But I'm not sure if one can create everything (ALB, IAM roles and policies, security groups, ebs, efs, rds, aws networking, ...) using terraform.

I want to learn aws by experimenting. But I cannot afford spending that much money. So I need to be able to destroy everything and recreate the exact infrastructure whenever it's needed.

I've found a really good [aws workshop](https://www.eksworkshop.com/). But like almost all of tutorials, it's based on running "eksctl and aws cli" commands.

Is there a reliable way of declaring everything once and recreate the whole infrastructure declarativly (without touching aws console)?

Comment: Have you checked the Terraform tutorial for EKS? https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/eks

Comment: @BabakNaffas No I haven't. But I will. Thanks a lot! But I want to be sure that it's possible and then dive into terraform / eks details.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.

I recommend to try this module - [github.com/cloudposse/terraform-aws-eks-cluster](https://github.com/cloudposse/terraform-aws-eks-cluster). Cloudposse is doing great job and their modules are well documented and maintained.